# Not allowing android app to be converted into .apk from google play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

With astro file manager and other applications, applications uploaded on google play can be backed up as .apk file. However some apps can't be backed up using these applications.
I want to know that is there any way in android source code that would protect google play applcations not backed up as .apk file?

Comment: @Harish Aftab, If the app registered with google to protect back up data,you can't able to back up the app to apk. refer http://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html

Answer (score 1):

```
applications uploaded on google play can be backed up as .apk file.
```

Applications that are marked as **public applications** by the publisher can be backed up to the SD card.

> However some apps can't be backed up using these applications.

**Android does not allow applications that are marked as private to be backed up**. This includes most paid applications. Private applications can be re-installed from the market if necessary.

> is there any way in android source code that would protect google play
>   applcations not backed up as .apk file?

you can **define you application marked as private to be backed up while publishing your app** with this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html). and after user  can not be backed up your application to the SD card